# Check if a scalar falls within the range given by sub-arrays of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a rank 3 matrix:

```
r = {{{1, 10}, {19, 71}, {111, 159}}, {{1, 5}, {25, 63}, {118, 132}, {164, 185}}, {{1, 19}, {28, 49}, {157, 203}}};
```

and each of the sub-arrays above represents a range. No two sub-arrays in a given row has any overlap.

I want to check if given `i` of `r[[i]]` and a scalar `x`, I want to check if any of the sub-arrays have `x` within their range.

e.g. if `i =2` and `x=175` is TRUE because `{164,185}` has it, but `x=75` is FALSE since none of the  `{1, 5}, {25, 63}, {118, 132}, {164, 185}` has it.

I do not want to use `MapThread` and use compilable functions, `UnitStep` if possible.

Comment: I'm happy to be able to quickly answer this one for you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. Look for more brain picking from me on SE. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert your sub-arrays to [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) format:

```
r2 = Interval @@@ r;
```

Then you may use [`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html):

```
i = 2;
x = 175;

IntervalMemberQ[r2[[i]], x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

It will be difficult to compile a complete function for your problem because the input will need to be a rectangular tensor, and your data is not:

```
TensorQ[r]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

You could compile a function to check an individual sub-array but that is essentially what `IntervalMemberQ` already is I imagine.  If you find this test to be the performance bottleneck in your code you should post the context in which you are using it (in a new question) so that other recommendations might be made.

Comment: Another gem!!...but is `IntervalMemberQ` compilable?

Comment: @brama Why would it need to be compilable?  It is already a fast System function.  Are you creating code for export to another language, e.g. C?

Comment: I was planning to use it in an already compiled code. Unfortunately, `NoneTrue` is not compilable. If I do not find any compilable functions to do it, I might still go with `IntervalMemberQ` and uncompilable function if it performs better than compilable with `MapThread`.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: If you have **V10**, then:

```
f[r_, i_, scalar_] := AnyTrue[r[[i]], #[[1]] <= scalar <= #[[2]] &]
```

Otherwise,

```
f[r_, i_, scalar_] := ! VectorQ[r[[i]], Not[#[[1]] <= scalar <= #[[2]]] &]
```

Check:

```
f[r, 2, 175]
```

> True

```
f[r, 2, 75]
```

> False

Comment: Echo my comment to Algohi: it is highly inefficient to expand intervals to an explicit range of numbers.  It also works only for integer `x` values, assuming a step size of `1`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I agree. I was just working on a fix.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. See edit.

Comment: Sorry to keep criticizing, but the problem with `Or @@` is that you test every interval even if the first one is a match.  This is why I used `NoneTrue`. +1 for making this a function however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, your criticisms are appreciated and thanks. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I had a laugh upon seeing your update.  I guess I forgot about `AnyTrue` -- for some reason I remembered `AllTrue` and `NoneTrue` but not that one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yeah, I was wondering why you didn't use it. I guess that explains it :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
x = 175;
Map[MemberQ[#, x] &, Apply[Range, r, {2}], {2}]

(*{{False, False, False}, {False, False, False, True}, {False, False, 
  True}}*)
```

Comment: This is much less efficient than it could be as you expand each interval rather than merely comparing end points.  See my updated answer for how one might approach this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pick[r, ! Cases[#, {x_, y_} /; x <= 175 <= y] == {} & /@ r]
```

If you just want to check if the number belongs to any interval in a row of `r`:

```
!Cases[#,{x_,y_}/;x<=175<=y]=={}&/@r
(* {False,True,True} *)

!Cases[#,{x_,y_}/;x<=75<=y]=={}&/@r
(* {False,False,False} *)
```